# Printing elements of a linked list, but instead, it prints reversed C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

here i simply wanted to print the elements of the linked list i created but it is printing the list in REVERSE order. looks like there is a mistake in the code.help me solve it
push function adds node to linked list every time we input element to be inserted in linked list.I've passed reference of head and data. A node gets dynamically created every time push fuction called. I am using c++ here.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};
//creating linked list 
    void push(node** head_ref,int new_data) //passing address of head and data to put in list
    {

        node* new_node=new node(); //new node created
        new_node->data=new_data;   //data inserted
        new_node->next=*(head_ref);
        *(head_ref)=new_node;
    }

int main()
{
    node* head=NULL;

    int n;
    cin>>n; //number of elements in linked list
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int val;
        cin>>val;
        push(&head,val); //push function which creates a linked list

    }

//while loop for printing elements of linked list
        while(head!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<head->data;
            head=head->next;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you are _creating_ the list in reverse order. Take a close look at where the new node is appended.

Comment: what you are doing is always prepending to the new head, which implies filling the list "backwards", i.e. last element is pushed in front of the last head. Instead, try assigning (*head_ref)->next=new_node

Answer (score 0):

What you currently do is assigning each node to be the predecessor of the current head, so in the end your head will be the latest element you added , its successor the second last element,  its successor the third last element etc. and thus resulting to a reversed list.

You should assign the new node as *successor* of the current "head", like this:

```
void push(node** tail_ref,int new_data) //passing address of tail and data to put in list
{
    node* new_node=new node(); //new node created
    new_node->data=new_data;   //data inserted
    (*tail_ref)->next= new_node;
    *(tail_ref)=new_node;
}
```

Note that I renamed `head_ref` to `tail_ref` in the snippet above, which better describes what the pointer actually represents: a pointer to the current last element of the list, hence the tail of the list.

Of course, you will need to save the pointer to the first element. Otherwise you won't be able to iterate through your linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241022/simon)'s answer, which is correct so far:

You already have a class 'node' – why not create a class 'list' or 'linked_list' as well:

```
class LinkedList
{
    node* m_head = nullptr;
    node* m_tail = nullptr;
};
```

Now you always have head and tail combined and don't need to store them separately. Note that in above example, they are both *private*. That's actually how you should design your class. If you don't, then you allow a user to break the list implementation from outside (someone might, for instance, just set one of these pointers to nullptr, producing a memory leak in case of head).

However, now you will have to provide appropriate means to access and modify the list:

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    void append(int new_data);  // as Simon proposed
    void prepend(int new_data); // your implementation
    int head();
    int tail();
    void dropHead();
    //void dropTail(); // is an O(n) operation with singly linked list, though!
private:
    node* m_head = nullptr;
    node* m_tail = nullptr;
};
```

The node class is very closely linked to your list, you might consider not letting it be a stand-alone class, but making it a nested class instead. There's yet quite a bit to add (e. g. how to iterate over the list). To get some hints I recommend to peek a bit into STL and get familiar with the concept of iterators.

Finally: Stop re-inventing the wheel. STL already provides fully implemented doubly (`std::list`) and singly (`std::forward_list`) linked lists. It's fine to experiment with an own implementation to get to know how the winds blow, but once you know, switch back to STL.